# How to Change Orienation of FireTV/FireStick for Digital Signage

Tags: android-tv, landscape-portrait, amazon-fire-tv

I'm attempting to build a digital signage app, it is almost done. The thing I'm having trouble with right now is changing the orientation of the `Activity`.

So, when I call the `requestedOrientation = SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`, the orientation change animation does show, however the view is still being layout in the landscape the only difference is, now the view is Horizontally shrunk (which stretches the views horizontally) and Vertically stretched (which shrinks the views vertically).

For better understanding, here is the app's screenshot in landscape:

[image: Landscape widget layout]

and in Portrait:

[image]